# Почему не отсылается код? Codeforces

Tags: python

Сегодня зарегался на codeforces и решил начать с самых легких задач. https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/977/A. Возможно я что-то не знаю как правильно отсылать или еще что. Но мое решение не работает, хотя сколько не тестил у себя все ок. Может я как-то неправильно считываю данные или еще что? У себя Python 3.8.2, когда отправляю - выбираю 3.7.2

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())
while k > 0:
    if n % 10 == 0:
        n /= 10
    else:
        n -= 1
    k -= 1
print(int(n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На будущее, в codeforces'e можно посмотреть детали тестирования (входные данные и ошибки)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На счёт вашего кода, прочитайте про формат входных данных внимательней:

> Входные данные:
>
> Первая **СТРОКА** входных данных содержит два целых числа n и k ...

Считывание в одну строку:

```
n, k = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```